# Event like componentDidUpdate, but fired only once

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have some components that should do some work as soon as their data has arrived and rendered for the first time, but not for future rerenderings. For example: Comments are loaded and rendered, now 1. load social media libraries and 2. load some Google Analytics.

Right now I'm doing it like that:

```
componentDidUpdate: function (prevProps, prevState) {
    if (this.hasAlreadyUpdatedOnce) {
        // ... do some stuff...
    } else {
        // ... do some stuff that should happen only once...
        // 1. load social media libraries
        // 2. load some Google Analytics
        this.hasAlreadyUpdatedOnce = true;
    }
}
```

But I'm asking myself if there's a more elegant way than setting a property like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you're responding to a state change, you should pass a callback as the second argument to setState.

```
componentDidMount: function(){
  ajaxyThing(function(data){
    this.setState({data: data}, function(){
      // this.state is updated, the component has rerendered 
      // and the dom is current
    });
  }.bind(this));
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You want `componentDidMount()`. [Details here.](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#mounting-componentdidmount)

Comment: But at `componentDidMount`, my initial ajax requests haven't happened yet, meaning the DOM is there, but empty. The operations I want to perform require the DOM to contain the data from the initial ajax request. Or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: you should load the data in a parent component and pass it in as props so that you can have the data when it mounts

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried updating state once the ajax call has finished?
Or you can return false for componentShouldUpdate and once the ajax call promise has resolved call forceUpdate.

Answer (score 0):

I can't give you a definitive answer because I don't know if your ajax call is in the parent or child component but either way you should be able to leverage `shouldComponentUpdate()` to accomplish your goals. If you really don't ever want to update your component after the ajax call comes in then you can do something like this:
    shouldComponentUpdate() {
      return false;
    }

and then when your ajax call comes back just run `this.forceUpdate()`. returning false will make it so that your component never updates unless you run `this.forceUpdate()`. However this is not the best solution to the problem I just can't give a better one without more information.

Answer (score 0):

The [React docs](http://facebook.github.io/react/tips/initial-ajax.html) have a good example on how to handle this using [`isMounted()`](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#ismounted).

> `isMounted()` returns true if the component is rendered into the DOM,
>   false otherwise. You can use this method to guard asynchronous calls
>   to `setState()` or `forceUpdate()`.

**Example**

First, initialize your state variables in `getInitialState()':

```
getInitialState: function() {
  return {
    username: '',
    lastGistUrl: ''
  }
}
```

In `componentDidMount()` make the ajax call (`$.get` in this case) then re-set the state variables:

```
componentDidMount: function() {
  $.get(this.props.source, function(result) {
    var lastGist = result[0];
    if (this.isMounted()) {
      this.setState({
        username: lastGist.owner.login,
        lastGistUrl: lastGist.html_url
      });
    }
  }.bind(this));
}
```